# 8 variables for 12 months. Sigmaplot

Tags: regression, time-series, correlation, statistical-significance, anova

I have measeured 8 variables for 12 months. n = 5-20. So, now I have mean, STDEV, SEM and n for those variables. I have trying to show relationship within those variables and among months. So, I decided to follow One way Between Sample ANOVA and One way repeated measure ANOVA test in SigmaPlot. Is this seems ok?

Comment: Do you have the original measurements or just the summary statistics? Was it one measurement per month?

Comment: Original measurement. Monthly sampling but not of equal duration

Answer (score 0):

ANOVA is a not a good measure here. Because ANOVA compares means between variables(categories). For suppose consider VAR1 has values (1,2,3,4,5,6) and VAR2 has values(4,3,5,1,2) . In this case both variables have same means but dont follow same pattern.

I also raised the question to know the test for finding relation among multiple variables(items) over the last 30 days.

[Statistic test for correlation among multiple variables || statistical test for confirming sales pattern among multiple items](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/210528/statistic-test-for-correlation-among-multiple-variables-statistical-test-for)